# How to get path of loaded image in c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I loaded image for a click event.
For another event i need to get path of loaded image
here's my code for loading image

```
Image img = new Image(); 
Stream imageStreamSource = new FileStream("img/block.png", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read); 
PngBitmapDecoder decoder = new PngBitmapDecoder(imageStreamSource,BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat,BitmapCacheOption.Default); 
BitmapSource bitmapSource = decoder.Frames[0]; 
ImageSource imageSource = bitmapSource; 
img.Source = imageSource
```

Is there any way to get path of img as string value or different??
Because i want to compare it's path for other event

Comment: Why not just keep the path around in memory?

Comment: Just put the string "img/block.png" as a private member variable so its available to both click events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try casting to FileStream to get full path

```
 FileStream fStream = imageStreamSource as FileStream;
 var filePath = fStream.Name;
```